# If $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = 0$, then what can we say about $\lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{n \to \infty} g(nh)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let’s say I have a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that : $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = 0$ ($n$ is an integer).

Then I was wondering, what can I say about the following double limit :

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{n \to \infty} g(nh)$$

The problem here is that it seems that it’s $0$, because we first apply $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, but does it mean that if we switch the limits the result is $g(0)$ ?

Comment: You need to confirm if $n$ is restricted to be an integer.

Comment: Yes, mb it does stand for  integers.

Comment: Then the values of $g(nh)$ are independent of those of $g(n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer $\lim_{h\to0}$ takes any small $h$ (as in, close to $0$ but not actually $0$) and evaluates whatever is inside that limit expression. For any small, but positive $h$, the expression does evaluate to $0$, so the entire limit is also $0$.

Almost.

There are a few subtleties. One of them is that we don't know what happens for *negative* $h$, as a negative $h$ would mean we care about $\lim_{n\to-\infty}g(n)$. That can be solved by restricting ourselves to positive $h$ by writing $\lim_{h\to 0^+}$ instead.

The other subtlety is that when you use $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, using the letter $n$, it's implied that you're looking at *integers*, by convention. That doesn't have to be true. While unusual, there is nothing wrong with letting $n$ represent real numbers rather than integers. If $n$ does indeed refer only to integers, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=0$ tells us next to nothing about $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(hn)$ as $h\to0$.

If $n$ represents integers, and we know $g$ is decreasing (or just *eventually* decreasing), then $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=0$ implies $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$ for real $x$, and the argument I use in the first paragraph holds completely.

Comment: I am pretty sure $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ stands for limits through integers. It becomes difficult for Mathematicians to communicate with each other if we don't  follow some standards in the notations we use.

Comment: Ok, thank you. In the case where I add the extra condition : $g$ is decreasing. Then (supposing $n$ is an integer and $h$ a real number) what can I say about : $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \lim_{n \to +\infty} g(nh)$ ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy As I said, it is _convention_ to let $n$ represent integers. It's definitely the most common interpretation. But that doesn't mean it's _wrong_ to let $n\in\Bbb R$, and that's why it needs to be _specified_. It isn't in the problem statement, so it's ambiguous.

Comment: @Kfnldnffk Yes, if a function is decreasing (or if it's increasing), then the limit towards $\infty$ over the integers and over the reals is necessarily the same.

Comment: "For any small, but positive $h$, the expression does evaluate to $0$, so the entire limit is also $0$."  I don't see this.

Comment: @zhw. I do address a few caveats in the paragraphs below the first one. Maybe they clarify things.

Comment: All we know is that $\lim_{n\to \infty} g(n)=0.$ Why should $\lim_{n\to \infty} g(nh)=0$ even exist for small $h>0?$

Comment: If either 1) $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ refers to reals, or 2) $g$ is (eventually) monotonous, then yes it definitely does.

Comment: @zhw. In either of those cases, for a direct proof from the definition of limit, given an $\epsilon>0$, pick an $N$ which works for $g(n)$. Then $N/h$ works for $g(hn)$.

Answer (score 4):

False: let $g(x)=\sin (\pi x)$. Then $\lim g(n) =0$ but $\lim g(nh) $ does not even exist for $h=\frac 1 k$, $k=1,2,...$. If $g$ is decreasing and you take limit as $h \to 0$ through positive values then the iterated limit equals the infimum of $g$ which is $0$ so the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: Ok, thank you. In the case where I add the extra condition : $g$ is decreasing. Then (supposing $n$ is an integer and $h$ a real number) what can I say about : $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \lim_{n \to +\infty} g(nh)$ ?